# How to save/restore a snapshot of an emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an emulator running in Android Studio, with my app loaded and setup, and I now want to snapshot the emulator so I can restore the device back to its original state following some testing. This doesn't seem possible.

I've tried telnet using "avd snapshot foo" - nothing happened.

I've also tried copying the AVD image files (folder and .ini) and doctoring the ini to look at the copied folder. AVD manager recognises and lists the copy, but thinks the original and the copy are the same when running/stopping them.

I've also tried using the Duplicate option in AVD, but this just seems to update/edit the existing one.

Also tried the Android Device Monitor - nothing here either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean screeshot ?

Comment: No. I want to save the state of the whole device. Like with VMs when you snaphsot the whole virtual device which you can then restore again at some point in the future.